# Compare content of two lists

Tags: java

I want to compare the content of two Lists, in particular a certain method of the custom object stored in both of these lists, let's call it `#getID()`.

My approach is to have a method that tells me whether those two lists contain the same entries with the same IDs.

```
List<CustomObject> firstList;
List<CustomObject> secondList;
```

Looping through each entry in `firstList`, calling getID() on it and look if there is an object in `secondList` that returns the same value for getID().

What would be an efficient way to do this check? Preferably using Java 8 streams, they seam quite useful here.

Answer (score 1):

If both lists are sorted you can do that:

```
public boolean equalsLists(List<YourClass> a, List<YourClass> b) {
    if (a.size() != b.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if (!a.get(i).getId().equals(b.get(i).getId()) {
             return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you can sort the elements, sort them and apply the same algorithm shown before.

Otherwise the efficiency of your algorithm depends on many factors:

- How often two lists can be equals
- How long are the lists
- If elements can be present more than one time in the list
- If it is possible to apply a function to all the elements to know with reasonable safeness if two lists are not equals use this function before comparing element by element (for example, if you have strings of different size to check you can count the number of chars of each id of each list and if they are different you are sure that you can return false)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both lists are sorted, you could use a `comparator`.

```
        Comparator<List<CustomObject>> myComp = new Comparator<List<CustomObject>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(List<CustomObject> customObjectList, List<CustomObject> t1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < customObjectList.size(); i++) {
                    if (customObjectList.getId().equals(t1.getId())) {
                        // Do your logic here
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        myComp.compare(list1, list2);
```

This is the "Java" way of doing things. If the lists are mismatched in size, you will have to practice some sort of defensive programming. If they are not sorted, you can use `Collections.sort` prior to comparing these two lists.

Comment: I should have mentioned that, it's a String!

Answer (score 0):

One approach of getting repeated elements is using a Map as follows.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SomeClass {
    protected class Component {
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public Component(String id, String description) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.description = description;
        }

        String id;
        String description;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return "Id " + this.getId();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Component component1 = new SomeClass().new Component("1", "One");
        Component component2 = new SomeClass().new Component("2", "One");
        Component component3 = new SomeClass().new Component("1", "One");
        Component component4 = new SomeClass().new Component("3", "Three");
        Component component5 = new SomeClass().new Component("4", "Four");
        List<Component> list1 = new ArrayList<Component>();
        list1.add(component1);
        list1.add(component2);

        List<Component> list2 = new ArrayList<Component>();
        list1.add(component1);
        list1.add(component2);

        list2.add(component3);
        list2.add(component4);
        list2.add(component5);

        Map<String, Component> result = list2.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Component::getId, Function.identity()));

        Set<Component> repeated = list1.stream().filter(component -> result.containsKey(component.getId()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        repeated.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```